# += and }] keys sometimes refuse to work. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

for the past month these two particular keys have been more often than not, not registering at all; this includes when I plug in an external keyboard so it is not a keyboard issue. When I hold down shift and press them both at the same time, my computer will play a light beeping noise with each press indicating that there is still some kind of registration of the keys. I have tried updating my computer and running MalwareBytes but still have yet to found a solution.

If there are any more potential variables that could be causing this that I am unaware, I will answer swiftly; I am not the best when it comes to this type of computer stuff.